# Angular 2 matToolTip render HTML

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I know that matToolTip doesn't support HTML rendering, does anyone found a solution to do it?

In some other ways with matToolTip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the current version doesn't support HTML rendering, there is an opened feature issue https://github.com/angular/components/issues/19367 and maybe it will be available in the future.
for now, you could use [overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview)  for that. you can accomplish tooltip style component very ease with that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to insert HTML in that tooltip. Should you try other tooltip like ng-bootstrap or Tippy.js which support it